# UITableView re-make the cell on scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm unable to counter this problem. I'm working on an app that has a timeline and in a cell there is an image, some button and labels. There are three button in every cell one is love, second is comment and 3rd is share as shown in the picture.[image]
 Now when user selects the love button, I've coded that it changes it's image to a `filled-heart-icon`just like on instagram. Changing the images means **call has been sent to the web-server** and now if page refreshes it'll keep the image the way it is. This is done just to give user a feel that his change has been done, so the app sends this change data in the back and user didn't feel any lag because of it.
But if user liked a picture and scrolled down enough so that the image is out of screen and then decided to scroll up and that image will come again with a `heart-icon` not a `filled-heart-icon` but if he refreshes the timeline it'll be changed to `filled-heart-icon`.
So when a cell came back to the active portion of screen it changes to it's state of last downloaded content. I've checked my code and there is no call which is refreshing it again or anything else. My questions is where can I find this problem. I've checked my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method thrice but found nothing. If there is a need I'll add the code here but I think it's more of a properties of the table that needs to be addressed.

 I'm changing the heart icon instantly in `HomeCell.m` class as:

```
if ([self.loveBtn.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart-icon-filled"]])
    {
        [self.loveBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart-icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.loveBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart-icon-filled"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

And if the timeline refreshes it change the icon based on the server response i.e. 1 means liked 0 means un-liked. This image below is almost everything I wrote to give you a clear image of the problem.
[image]

 here is how the call is generated for love button. In my `HomeViewController` which has the timeline first I've registered the `NSNotifications` in `ViewWillApear` as:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(HomeLovePostSuccess) name:@"HomeLovePostSuccess" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(HomeLovePostFail:) name:@"HomeLovePostFail" object:nil];
```

and in `HomeLovePostSuccess` method this is what I'm not actually doing anything:
-(void)HomeLovePostSuccess
{
    NSString *uid = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:USERID];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:uid,@"uid", nil];
}
 but in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I'm calling the webserver:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
HomeCell *cellObj = (HomeCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HomeCell" ];
if ([[isLikeArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                    [cellObj.loveBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart-icon-filled"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                }
                else
                {
                    [cellObj.loveBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart-icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
return cellObj;
}
```

**I think this has something to do with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.**

Comment: It seems like you need to temporarily store which items have a pending call to "love". If you share your code it will be easier to help you. Also, I highly doubt it has anything to do with the table view properties.

Comment: You need to show the `cellForRowAtIndex` code - this is where you will be setting the image when the cell is displaydd

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm changing the image in HomeCell.m: `if ([self.loveBtn.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart-icon-filled"]])
    {
        [self.loveBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart-icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.loveBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart-icon-filled"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
`  This is for the immediate changing, after refresh the image change on the response from server.

Comment: @GuyKogus see my edited answer. and let me know which specific code you need to see? As I don't know which part to share.

Comment: You can't track state in the cell itself. You need to update your data model immediately so that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` can supply the correct image.

Comment: @Paulw11see the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

this has to do with how your loading and saving the state of the button.  In most cases you will use information from a Model object that will save different properties about the cell.  You would use this object when `tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called and in your case you would have a Bool representing what was liked or not.  When you send your state to the server, and you turn the "liked" state to true, you would then need to update the state of Bool in the model as well.  That way when your cell is off screen and then is loaded again in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it will know enough to change its state to "Liked".

As you haven't included any code, its hard to tell what your doing, so showing code would be more helpful as I'm assuming to what your solution is for saving the Liked state

Comment: What @paulw11 said, show us what cellForRowAtIndexPath is doing because that will get called again once that cell comes back on screen.  That is what is probably resetting whatever you previously did

Comment: see the edited version now. I've added the code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I think this has something to do with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`

Answer (score 0):

You need to focus on your MVC design. Your `HomeCell` is the **View** in this case. The `HomeViewController` is the **Controller** and passes each cell the **Model** to represent in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

You're doing this for the most part, but your **Model** is incomplete. There is an interim stage for liking an item that isn't being considered.

Consider something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   HomeCell *cellObj = (HomeCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HomeCell" ];
   if ([[isLikeArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"1"] ||
       [self.objectsBeingLiked contains:@(indexPath.row)])
   {
      [cellObj.loveBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart-icon-filled"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }
   else
   {
      [cellObj.loveBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart-icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }
   return cellObj;
}
```

`objectsBeingLiked` would be an `NSMutableSet` that contains the indices of any items that the user has requested to like but the server response is still pending. If there's something more appropriate to place in the set, use it. I leave that to your judgement.

Also, your `HomeLovePostSuccess` and `HomeLovePostFail:` methods could be used to reload the corresponding cell to indicate that loading has completed. If you use my above suggestion you would need to remove the necessary indices from `objectsBeingLiked` when these methods are called.